# Clone SVN repository locally

Tags: git, cygwin, git-svn

I try to clone svn repository locally with following command in cygwin:

```
git svn clone file:///J:/<path_to_repository>/svn_repo -s .
```

and I get following error:

```
svn: E235000: In file '/usr/src/subversion/subversion-1.7.8-2/src/subversion/subversion/libsvn_subr/dirent_uri.c' line 2315: assertion failed (svn_uri_is_canonical(url, pool))
```

what is wrong with my url?

**UPD**

```
$ git svn --version
git-svn version 1.7.9 (svn 1.7.8)
```

Comment: With `git-svn version 1.7.9 (svn 1.7.9)`, I was able to successfully issue the command you gave.  I used the file:///cygdrive/c/... syntax.  If the directory did not exist I get an error, but different from the one you got.  Maybe updating your git/svn versions will help.

Comment: @cforbish, have you successfully cloned local svn repository?

Comment: @cforbish, just tried to clone some other repository and managed to do that, however for one repository it seems to be cloning but does not fetch any data

Comment: @cforbish, just found that for some reason local svn repository was cloned at onle level higher, that is why my local `git-svn` clone was not working

Comment: I am glad you found the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in cygwin bash, you would need to modify the `J:` to `cygdrive/j`.

Comment: What does `git svn --version` return?